# How can I custom my DataTable in React App

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, html-table, datatable

I found a tutorial to implement DataTable in React App but I have no idea how can I custom my tr, td, colspan etc...

My DataTable.js is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.$el = $(this.el);
        this.$el.DataTable({
            data: this.props.data,
            columns: this.props.columns
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table" ref={el => this.el = el}>

                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And after in my Test.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DataTable from './DataTable';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            columns: [
                { title: "Id" },
                { title: "Category" },
                { title: "Title" },
                { title: "Command 1" },
                { title: "Command 2" },
                { title: "Command 3" }
            ]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._getFilteredItems();
    }

    _getFilteredItems = () => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/items/category', { category: "category1" })
            .then((res) => {
                var test = res.data.map((e) => Object.values(e)); // to transform objet in array
                this.setState({ data: test });
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
    }

    display = () => {
        if(this.state.data.length > 0){
            return (
                <DataTable
                    data={this.state.data}
                    columns={this.state.columns}>
                </DataTable>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {this.display()}

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

My data received from my backend is like this :

```
[
 ["5e9c231facad1424801f5167", "category1", "title", "command1", "command2", "command3"],
 ["5e9c2337acad1424801f58ce", "category1", "title", "command1", "command2", "command3"],
 ["5eaa105b82d1130017d31dbe", "category1", "title", "command1", "command2", "command3"],
]
```

The thing is I would like to custom my tr, td, colspan etc... I mean, I would like for example put the title with a colspan="5" and my command1, command2 and command3 in the same td.

Do you have any idea how can I do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, I simply initialized my table as I wanted in the render instead of using props like the tutorial mentionned it :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._getFilteredItems();
    }

    _getFilteredItems = () => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/items/category', { category: "category1" })
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({data: res.data});
      
                this.$el = $(this.el);
                this.$el.DataTable({});
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table" ref={el => this.el = el}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Commands</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map((elmt, i) => (
                        <tr key={i}>
                            <td>
                                {elmt.title}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {elmt.command1} <br/>
                                {elmt.command2} <br/>
                                {elmt.command3} <br/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```